# What advantages do StableNames have over reallyUnsafePtrEquality#, and vice versa?

Tags: haskell, ghc

data [StableName](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Mem-StableName.html#t:StableName) a

> Stable names have the following property: 
>    If sn1 :: StableName and sn2 :: StableName and sn1 == sn2 then sn1 and sn2 were created by calls to makeStableName on the same object.
>
> The reverse is not necessarily true: if two stable names are not equal, then the objects they name may still be equal.

[reallyUnsafePtrEquality#](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#v:reallyUnsafePtrEquality-35-) :: a -> a -> Int#

reallyUnsafePtrEquality# returns whether two objects on the GHC heap are the same object. It's really unsafe because the garbage collector moves things around, closures, etc. To the best of my knowledge, it can return false negatives (it says two objects aren't the same, but they are), but not false positives (saying they're the same when they aren't).

Both of them seem to do the same basic thing: they can tell you whether two objects are definitely the same, but not whether they're definitely not.

The advantages I can see for StableNames are:

- They can be hashed.
- They are less nonportable.
- Their behaviour is well-defined and supported.
- They don't have reallyUnsafe as part of their name.

The advantages I can see for reallyUnsafePtrEquality#:

- It can be called directly on the objects in question, instead of having to create separate StablesNames.
- You don't have to go through an IO function to create the StableNames.
- You don't have to keep StableNames around, so memory usage is lower.
- The RTS doesn't have to do whatever magic it does to make the StableNames work, so performance is presumably better.
- It has reallyUnsafe in the name and a # at the end. Hardcore!

My questions are:

- Did I miss anything?
- Is there any use case where the fact that StableNames are separate from the objects they name is an advantage?
- Is either one more accurate (less likely to return false negatives) than the other?
- If you don't need hashing, don't care about portability, and aren't bothered by using something called reallyUnsafe, is there any reason to prefer StableNames over reallyUnsafePtrEquality#?

Comment: "To the best of my knowledge, it can return false negatives (it says two objects aren't the same, but they are), but not false positives (saying they're the same when they aren't)." I'm afraid [it can give false positives](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-June/079532.html), although that is extremely unlikely.

Comment: I can't remember where this was discussed (might've been IRC), but the two reasons I remember for why false positives are impossible were that GC only happens at allocation, not during primops, so there is no possible way it could interrupt reallyUnsafePtrEquality# to put one object where the other was; and that the GC's from-space and to-space are nonoverlapping, so even if it could, it wouldn't. Obviously if both false negatives and false positives were possible it would be completely useless.

Comment: That sounds plausible. But usually Edward K. knows what's up, so I'd rather double-check than blithely ignore his warnings. However, the second point pretty much rules out false positives (two GCs between looking at the two args for a primop seems a little too far-fetched), even if one doesn't completely trust the first.

Comment: Edward K. was actually part of the discussion I referenced, if I'm not misremembering. :) I'll link it if I find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Holding the `StableName` of an object doesn't prevent it from being garbage collected, whereas holding the object itself around (to use with `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` later) does. Sure, you can use [`System.Mem.Weak`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Mem-Weak.html), but at that point, why not just use a `StableName`? (In fact, weak pointers were added with `StableName`s.)

Being able to hash them is the main motivator for `StableName`s, as the documentation says:

> We can't build a hash table using the address of the object as the key, because objects get moved around by the garbage collector, meaning a re-hash would be necessary after every garbage collection.

In general, if `StableName`s will work for your purposes, I'd use them, even if you need to use `unsafePerformIO`; if you really need `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`, you'll know. The only example I can think of where `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` would work and `StableName`s wouldn't is speeding up an expensive `Eq` instance:

```
x == y =
    x `seq` y `seq`
    case reallyUnsafePtrEquality# x y of
        1# -> True
        _  -> slowEq x y
```

There's probably other examples I just haven't thought of, but they're not common.

Comment: Good point about garbage collection and System.Mem.Weak. Though I guess the corollary is: in what situations would you want to store StableNames apart from the named objects? Hash tables are one, are there others? Regarding your last point, is there any specific reason you would prefer StableNames in general? (And is there actually a situation where StableNames wouldn't be suitable, and reallyUnsafePtrEquality# would be?)

Comment: @illissius: Well, memoisation with hash tables was the [motivating example](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/weak.pdf) for `StableName`s and weak pointers, so that's by far the most prominent example. They're also useful for [observable sharing](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~andygill/papers/reifyGraph.pdf).

Comment: I've updated my post with an example of when `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` would work but `StableName`s wouldn't.

Comment: As for as why I would prefer them in general, just the fact that they act more consistently and were designed as a public interface is good enough for me. I would consider leaping straight to `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` premature optimisation of a very dangerous sort.

Comment: Ah, short-circuiting (==) was actually the main case I had in the back of my mind when asking the question. Seems to me there's nothing here that rules out using StableNames either (at least if slowEq is expensive enough), but "why would I, when I could use reallyUnsafePtrEquality#?" was part of what motivated the question. But it seems we're in agreement here.

Comment: Thanks for linking the observable sharing paper. According to a bit near the end, before and after an object is evaluated is actually the *only* case where Eq on StableNames returns false negatives, though the documentation doesn't guarantee this, which means it's probably the more accurate of the two and answers another of my questions.