# How efficient is the derived Eq instance in GHC?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Is there a *short circuit* built in to GHC's (and Haskell's in general) derived `Eq` instance that will fire when I compare the same instance of a data type?

```
-- will this fire?
let same = complex == complex
```

My plan is to read in a lazy datastructure (let's say a tree), change some values and then compare the old and the new version to create a diff that will then be written back to the file.

If there would be a short circuit built in then the compare step would break as soon as it finds that the new structure is referencing old values. At the same time this wouldn't read in more than necessary from the file in the first place.

I know I'm not supposed to worry about references in Haskell but this seems to be a nice way to handle lazy file changes. If there is no shortcircuit builtin, would there be a way to implement this? Suggestions on different schemes welcome.

Comment: You could get similar short-circuiting if you attach a hash value to each tree node, but I agree that just being able to compare references (which are, in a way, hashes assigned by the memory management!) would be rather more straighforward and arguably just more efficient here. +1

Comment: What about [StableName](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Mem-StableName.html#t%3aStableName). I just found out about it. Would that help me in any way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StableNames are specifically designed to solve problems like yours.

Note that StableNames can only be created in the `IO` monad. So you have two choices: either *create* your objects in the `IO` monad, or use `unsafePerformIO` in your `(==)` implementation (which is more or less fine in this situation).

But I should stress that it is possible to do this in a totally safe way (without `unsafe*` functions): only creation of stable names should happen in `IO`; after that, you may compare them in a totally pure way.

E.g.

```
data SNWrapper a = SNW !a !(StableName a)

snwrap :: a -> IO (SNWrapper a)
snwrap a = SNW a <$> makeStableName a

instance Eq a => Eq (SNWrapper a) where
  (SNW a sna) (SNW b snb) = sna == snb || a == b
```

Notice that if stable name comparison says "no", you still need to perform full value comparison to get a definitive answer.

In my experience that worked pretty well when you have lots of sharing and for some reason are not willing to use other methods to indicate sharing.

(Speaking of other methods, you could, for example, replace the `IO` monad with a `State Integer` monad and generate unique integers in that monad as an equivalent of "stable names".)

Another trick is, if you have a recursive data structure, make the recursion go through `SNWrapper`. E.g. instead of

```
data Tree a = Bin (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
type WrappedTree a = SNWrapper (Tree a)
```

use

```
data Tree a = Bin (WrappedTree a) (WrappedTree a) | Leaf a
type WrappedTree a = SNWrapper (Tree a)
```

This way, even if short-circuiting doesn't fire at the topmost layer, it might fire somewhere in the middle and still save you some work.

Comment: That's more or less exactly what i have implemented now. So i'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's no short-circuiting when both arguments of `(==)` are the same object. The derived `Eq` instance will do a structural comparison, and in the case of equality, of course needs to traverse the entire structure. You can build in a possible shortcut yourself using

```
GHC.Prim.reallyUnsafePtrEquality# :: a -> a -> GHC.Prim.Int#
```

but that will in fact fire only rarely:

```
Prelude GHC.Base> let x = "foo"
Prelude GHC.Base> I# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# x x)
1
Prelude GHC.Base> I# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# True True)
1
Prelude GHC.Base> I# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# 3 3)
0
Prelude GHC.Base> I# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# (3 :: Int) 3)
0
```

And if you read a structure from file, it will certainly not find it the same object as one that was already in memory.

You can use rewrite rules to avoid the comparison of lexically identical objects

```
module Equal where

{-# RULES
"==/same"  forall x. x == x = True
  #-}

main :: IO ()
main = let x = [1 :: Int .. 10] in print (x == x)
```

which leads to

```
$ ghc -O -ddump-rule-firings Equal.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Equal            ( Equal.hs, Equal.o )
Rule fired: Class op enumFromTo
Rule fired: ==/same
Rule fired: Class op show
```

the rule firing (note: it didn't fire with `let x = "foo"`, but with user-defined types, it should).

Comment: I think lexigraphically equality won't get me far here. I'll have a look into reallyUnsafePtrEquality (altough reallyUnsafe scares me).  The references will (hopefully) be the same. I want to compare two trees after a `Tree -> Tree` function. Something of type `(Tree -> Tree) -> Changes`. I could of course keep a log of all the changes, but that strikes me as inefficient when i can just compare references.

Comment: Hmm ... reallyUnsafePtrEquality seems to have a big chance to fail. In a situation where every false negative incures a disc read thats bad.

Comment: Okay, if you compare `tree` to `fun tree`, there's a nonzero chance that `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` detects common subtrees. But yes, you must expect that it will often not detect equality.

Comment: Maybe you can add a paragraph about `StableName`? I'll accept your answer nevertheless, but i've just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649500/what-advantages-do-stablenames-have-over-reallyunsafeptrequality-and-vice-vers) and StableNames seem to be the way to go.

Comment: @Florian (and Daniel), it does work. With some `seq` magic: `let x = [1]; y = 1:x; y' = tail y in x \`seq\` y' \`seq\` I# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# x y')` gives 1. (And presumably it would work on a more complex data structure where there are unchanged substructures.)

Comment: @dbaupp The problem is that `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` is (presumably) based on the memory location. And that may change after every garbage collector iteration.

Comment: Maybe i can use `rUPE#` (there is a reason why this functions name is that long) as a fast first check. After that i'll resort to StableNames or hashes.

Comment: @Florian The name is long and scary to prevent people from using it if they don't really really want it. It produces a lot of false negatives, so it's indeed of limited use (but where it fires, it can save a lot of work). Concerning `StableName`s, I don't know if you'd have a realistic chance of getting the same `StableName` if you `makeStableName` of the left subtree of one tree, and the right subtree of another if they happen to be the same object. If not, you'd need to create and store them on creation, and create new ones on mutation, so you'd be very tied into `IO`.

Comment: I just realized that that is in part true. I don't want deduplication (same object in left and right tree). But there can't be a `Tree -> Tree` function that updates the `StableNames`. Altough as was pointed out somewhere above this may be a legit situation to use unsafePerformIO ...