# Haskell: get memory address of a list

Tags: haskell

is there a way to get the address of data element (say a list element) in Haskell.

```
combineLists :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

combineLists [] y = y
combineLists (x:xs) y = x : combineLists xs y

*Main> let x=[1,23, 12, 45]
*Main> x
[1,23,12,45]
*Main> let y =[90, 56, 78]
*Main> y
[90,56,78]
*Main> let z = combineLists x y
*Main> z
[1,23,12,45,90,56,78]
```

Now would `z` be constructed completely by copying elements from x and y (internal haskell representation) or

would z be something like: z = [ [copy of all elements from x] y]

I wanted to see if &y == &z[4] (z[4] = 90).

Also is there a way to dump the internal representation using something similar to ctypes in Python.

Thanks.

Comment: A list is not an array, it is represented by an array, but a linked list. The elements from `y` are not copied: only a reference is set... Some variables thus share the same substructure.

Comment: it will depend on the implementation and there are surely people around who can explain at least the GHC side directly (not me). Having said that: I doubt that any implementation would *copy* `y` instead of just reusing it

Comment: Here is a nice example (and of course you reimplemented it yourself) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Linked_lists

Comment: @CommuSoft: Thanks. you mentioned only a reference is set, is there a way to see that in GHCI? any existing module, that would help me investigate this? yes list is not array found it easier to use a array representation when asking the question.

Comment: The internal representation is quite sophisticated. There's the ghc-vis tool which shows it, but you will need to understand the runtime, which is very different from any imperative language. You have been warned :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`StableName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html#t%3AStableName) or [`reallyUnsafePointerEquality#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:20) (note the name and don't use in real programs; you'll also need [MagicHash](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) extension to call it) to check whether two expressions refer to the same object. See [What advantages do StableNames have over reallyUnsafePtrEquality#, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649500/what-advantages-do-stablenames-have-over-reallyunsafeptrequality-and-vice-vers) for the differences.

Comment: There are a very few packages that use it for very special purposes. It's really not something any beginner needs to touch with a ten-foot pole, and I would bet an ice cream sundae that under 5% of *experienced* Haskell programmers have used it even once.